# Height Maps for story driven terrain

Tags: terrain, level-design, heightmap

We are developing an indie story driven adventure game and our writer is writing specific geography into her story. Is there any information on how to create height maps for specific geography? I have googled and there is nothing specific I can find on controlling the painting to create a very specific geography. I have taken the common sense approach of black being nothing and pure white being the tallest points however our results have been negligible thus far.

Comment: Heightmaps should only create a base for your terrain. They usually lack in details. Just look at Skyrim. It's a story driven game utilizing a hashmap, but the rocks on the mountains are made with separate model.

Comment: I think that this question can not be properly answered without knowing what the author means with the results being "negligible" (what do they expect from their terrain system and what do they get instead?).This is an old question bumped by the Community bot, so I don't think that the author will still respond to clarification requests. I downvoted the question so the Community bot won't bump it again.

Comment: Phillip thanks for yet another down vote people love killing my score. Fact is I'm marking this as solved as I did solve the problem, I wrote a terrain generator for blender.

Comment: @TheGugaru don't be too discouraged by downvotes, they're just signals that someone thinks there's something we can improve. Here, adding details on what features "story driven terrain" needs that distinguishes this use case from other height maps, and what specific aspects of your results so far were not meeting your goals can help focus a question like this on more concrete solutions. Once questions are edited to be more focused in this way (especially with example images), they tend to attract up-votes to positively affect your reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good introduction tutorial on procedural terrain can be found at the [Red Blob Games blog](https://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/).

You will also find that at some point, height maps will not cut it any more. There will be no overhangs, no caves, no bridges or tunnels possible with a height map.

But depending on your needs, you could stick with a height map.

From the same author, there is also [this map generator](https://www.redblobgames.com/maps/mapgen2/), which is not a height map, but can help you get some ideas for controlling terrain features like rivers and such.